# На счету или на счете?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Недавно подруга спросила меня: "как правильно: "У нас на счету" или "на счете", если речь идет о бухгалтерии?"
Я ответила, что "на счете", а "на счету" было бы, если бы она сказала что-то вроде: "На моем счету три победы".
Правильно ли я ответила?

Comment: У аккуратного бухгалтера каждый рубль - на счету!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы абсолютно правы.

**На счету** используется обычно в переносном значении. За исключением, возможно, единичных и весьма спорных примеров.

Но уж в бухгалтерии - точно только **на счете**. При том, что многие бухгалтеры, особенно молодые, путают. 
Проще всего запомнить, если представить, что бухгалтерский счет сродни ресторанному. Это некий листочек с записями. И если на нем лежит, предположим, ручка, то вряд ли кто скажет "на счету", только "на счете".